# Div and text inside the div behaving weirdly

Tags: html, css

I want to center the text "name" horizontally and vertically inside the div "firstquad". I want the div to have 100% width and 25% height. But the div has much more than 100% width. For the text, I have set the top and left as 50%. The text should be centered and the div should fit the page horizontally but its like this. Any help?

```css
body {
  padding: 0%;
  margin: 0%;
  height: 300%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: cornsilk;
}

#firstquad {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  top: 0%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: blue;
}

#name {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="firstquad">
  <h1 id="name">ASEF DIAN</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: `text-align: center;` might help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

css:

```
body {
  padding: 0%;
  margin: 0%;
  height: 300%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: cornsilk;
}

#firstquad {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  top: 0%;
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#name {
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Both `div` and `h1` are block level elements by themselves.

Block level elements behave in such a way that

- they create a line break before and after themselves
- **they grab as much horizontal space as they can get**

Which means that with `<div><h1></h1></div>` you have a `div` that grabs as much horizontal space as available (full page width). Inside it, the `h1` behaves the same, consuming all horizontal space that the surrounding `div` allows.

Now with `position: relative; left: 50%;` you do not change the width of the `h1` - you simply change the position, where its rendering starts. Obviously, this leads to the `h1` moving partly outside the `div`. Add borders so you understand:

```css
body { margin: 30px; }

div { border: 2px dotted grey; }
h1 { border: 2px dashed blue; }
```

```html
<div><h1>Test</h1></div>
```

Now move the `h1` (only slightly, so the effect is visible better):

```css
body { margin: 30px; }

div { border: 2px dotted grey; }
h1 { border: 2px dashed blue; position: relative; left: 20px; }
```

```html
<div><h1>Test</h1></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
 body {
   margin: 0%;
   height: 100%;
   background-color: cornsilk;
 }

 #firstquad {
   height: 25%;
   background-color: blue;
   text-align: center;
 }

 #name {
   color: white;
   margin: 0;
 }
```

```html
<div id="firstquad">
  <h1 id="name">ASEF DIAN</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: It only centers horizontally, how do i center vertically? vertical-align: middle; does not work

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

Just change #name to `#name {
      color: white;
    }`

```css
  body {
      padding: 0%;
      margin: 0%;
      height: 300%;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: cornsilk;
    }

    #firstquad {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 50%;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: blue !important;
    }

    #name {
      color: white;
    }
```

```html
<div id="firstquad">
      <h1 id="name">ASEF DIAN</h1>
    </div>
```

Comment: How do i center it vertically?